# 2D character edit /create application

Tags: animation, 2d

I want to make an application(to run on windows) for creating or editing 2d characters.
I want to transform the outline, change color/components.

Which libraries do i need? In which platform can i program?

Answer (score 0):

There are many options:

i would suggest using C# with [XNA](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23714) framework (it is built for 2d & 3d animation).

there are many tutorials around [here is one](http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials.shtml) with 2d development explained.